# Curl Sending requests

Tags: c, networking, libcurl

This code sends requests successfully. I want to generate this error [CURLE_SEND_ERROR] what can I modify in code to make this error appear.

Is there is option can I do to make the request fail?

code Is:

```
if(strcmp(XMLFILE, SIM_INFO_RESPONSE_JSON)==0)
{
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);// 120 seconds for Service Directory
}
else
{
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,(long)CONN_TIMEOUT);
}

        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER,0L);
    
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, psHeader);
    
    
    
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_URL, psUrl);
    
    
    
    
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDSIZE,-1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, psBuf);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_POST,1L);
    
    if (strcmp(isWiFi, "WiFi") == 0)
    {
        
        
        
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "CRT");
        
        
        
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "rootCA.crt");
     
        
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0L);
        
        
        curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0L);
    }

#ifndef PRODMODE
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE,1L);
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_DEBUGFUNCTION, OnDebug);
#endif

    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteDataFunc);
    curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &nFd);

int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
    
        if (res == CURLE_OK)
            {
                ShowMsg("\r\n استقبال \r\n", 100);
                break;
            }
    }
```

I try to make this error appear CURLE_SEND_ERROR

Comment: Examine the source. Find what causes the error. Create that condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
        res = curl_easy_perform(pCurl);
        res = CURLE_SEND_ERROR;
```

... alternatively tell the OS to cut the internet connection in a CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, but how to cut the internet connection depends entirely on what OS you're using (eg Windows, Linux, or MacOS?)

for example if you're on Microsoft Windows, you could do something like

```c
curl_easy_setopt(pCurl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, [](void *clientp,
                                 double dltotal,
                                 double dlnow,
                                 double ultotal,
                                 double ulnow)->size_t{
        system("netsh winsock reset");
        return 0;
});
```

(untested)

Comment: I tried CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION but it returns error code 28 and this is not CURL SEND CODE Is there is other call back function in curl I can fail the connection in it  across sending request?